# std::list iterator strange behavior

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio, stl

for 2 days now, I have been trying to find out where is the problem in my code. I have isolated the problem like this:

There is loop which look like this:

```
int test_counter = 0; //Debug purpose only
for (const_iterator i = begin(); i != end(); i++, test_counter++){
    if ((*i)->isSoloed()) {
        soloed = (*i);
        break;
    }
}
```

It is in one method of the class that inherits std::list. The list contains pointers to some dynamically allocated instances of some class, but that is likely not important here.

The list contains exactly two pointers.

The problem is that in about 20% runs, the second pass (test_counter == 1) crashes on (*i)->isSoloed() with access violation. In this case, the iterator value is 0xfeeefeee. This exact value is used by VisualStudio to indicate that the memory has been freed. Well that doesn't make any sense from at least 3 reasons:

1. No memory gets dealocated here or in another threads
2. Even if so, how would the iterator get that value???
3. If in the case of
   crash (the exception window) I click break and look at the second
   items in the list looks intact and everything seems OK.

Note that this is a multithreaded code which is likely to be the problem here, but the loop is read-only (I even used the const_iterator) and the other thread that has the pointer to this list does not write in the time when the loop is running. But even so, how could that affect the value of the iterator which is a local variable here!

Thanks a lot.

//edit:
I have also noticed 2 more interesting things:

1) if I break the debugging after the access violation occurs, I can go back (by dragging the next commant to execute arrow) before the loop and run it again without any problem. So the problem is unfortunatelly pretty undeterministic.

2) I have never been able to reproduce the problem in release build.

The signature of the method:
MidiMessageSequence::MidiEventHolder* getNextActiveEvent();

and it is called like this:
currentEvent = workingTrackList->getNextActiveEvent();

nothing special really. The application uses JUCE library, but that shouldn't be a problem. I can post more code, just tell me what should I post.

Comment: Could you show a bit more context here please. What's the signature of that method, how do you call it?

Comment: Keep in mind that std::list is not designed to be inherited from (it has no virtual destructor, for example.)

Comment: I can easilly rewrite the code so that the list is agregated but there is no reason to think it is going to help. Anyway I will keep that in mind for future...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found out where exactly was the problem but I canceled the inheritance and agregated the std::list instead. With this the TrackList class became just a sort of wrapper around the std::list. I put a scoped lock in every method that accesses the list (in the wrapper, so from outside it works the same and I do not need to care about locking from outside) and this pretty much solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Two possible reasons.
1: The memory that i pointed to is deleted before it is accessed (*i). Try to add a check if(i) before access i (*i)->isSoloed().
2: Try to add a lock before you access the list or list item each time.

Comment: 1. That would not help as 0xfeeefeee would still pass the condition 2. I am about to do that but even then it would not explain that iterator value...